# Can I have nginx put stuff on memcached?

Tags: nginx, memcached

It is my understanding that [nginx can query memcached](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMemcachedModule) for data that it serves, but you have to place them there using some other (homegrown) program. So the question is, can I have nginx fetch data from the backend and place them into memcached for future use for certain locations?  Sort of not having to place all files from `/images` in it "by hand" but having them (mem)cached after being fetched for the first time?

Any backend other than memcached would suffice also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the page you linked to states, the backend (your application) must put the data into memcached.

Comment: Thank you. I am hoping for someone who has expanded the module and have nginx do that in a more generic way. If none, I'll give it a shot.